# Assignment from incompatible pointer type and derefrencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

I am trying to get chars and the number of each and put them into a linked list. As the title states i keep getting a warning about incompatible pointer types and an error about dereferencing incomplete type. I think the last one i said is because start is null but I dont see why when i assigned it to temp. Help please.

```
/* Author: Miller Kahihu
Date:  2017-02-01
Program getChars.c
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct linkedList
{
    struct Element* start;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct element
{
    char key;
    int value;
    struct Element* next;
} Element;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    LinkedList* list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    list->start = NULL;
    list->size = 0;

    char* fileName = NULL;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        fileName = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE* fpIn = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(!fpIn)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s could not be opened\n", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }
    int c;
    Element* temp = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));
    while((c=fgetc(fpIn)) !=EOF)
    {
        if(list->start == NULL)
        {
            temp->key = (char) c;
            temp->value = 1;
            temp->next = NULL;
            list->start = temp;
            printf("%c kappa\n", list->start->key);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c\n", (char) c);
        }
    }
    //free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the full error message

```
getChars.c: In function ‘main’:
getChars.c:51:25: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]                                                                 
         list->start = temp;
                     ^
getChars.c:52:45: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         printf("%c kappa\n", list->start->key);
                                         ^
```

Comment: seems that there's a parasite fwd decl of `Element`. And you should declare your Element struct before the linkedlist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is no such thing as a `struct Element`. `clang` gives a bit more of a clue in its warning.

```
test.c:52:25: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct Element *' from 'Element *'
      (aka 'struct element *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            list->start = temp;
                        ^ ~~~~
```

You have `struct element` and `Element` but no `struct Element`.

```
typedef struct element
{
    char key;
    int value;
    struct Element* next;
} Element;
```

Using differing cases is risking this goof. You're better off with something like this:

```
typedef struct Element
{
    char key;
    int value;
    struct Element* next;
} Element_t;
```

Using capital letters means you won't conflict with built ins. `struct Element` won't conflict with anything. And `Element_t` makes it obvious its a type and won't conflict with variable and function names.

Comment: Probably wouldn't want to use the `_t` suffix though, especially if he's going to targeting a POSIX system now or in the future.

Comment: @JeffMercado The capitalization should avoid a collision with POSIX types, yes?

Comment: Perhaps but I wouldn't risk it. The suffix is the restriction, not how everything else is capitalized so all are reserved. Same reason you shouldn't prefix anything with double underscores as they are reserved as well. Personally, the conventions I use are to prefix the struct name with an underscore and the actual type name without and capitalized. So all user defined types are capitalized.